# Time analysis of a Binary Search Tree in-order traversal algorithm

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, traversal, binary-search-tree

Below is an iterative algorithm to traverse a Binary Search Tree in in-order fashion (first `left child` , then the `parent` , finally `right child`) without using a Stack :

(Idea : the whole idea is to find the left-most child of a tree and find the successor of the node at hand each time and print its value , until there's no more node left.)

```
void In-Order-Traverse(Node root){
     Min-Tree(root); //finding left-most child
     Node current = root;
  while (current != null){
     print-on-screen(current.key);
     current = Successor(current);
  }
  return;
}

Node Min-Tree(Node root){ // find the leftmost child
   Node current = root;
   while (current.leftChild != null)
      current = current.leftChild;
   return current;
}

Node Successor(Node root){
  if (root.rightChild != null) // if root has a right child ,find the leftmost child of the right sub-tree
    return Min-Tree(root.rightChild);
  else{
    current = root;
    while (current.parent != null && current.parent.leftChild != current)
        current = current.parent;
    return current.parrent;
  }
}
```

It's been claimed that the time complexity of this algorithm is `Theta(n)` assuming there are `n` nodes in the BST , which is for sure correct . However I cannot convince myself as I guess some of the nodes are traversed more than constant number of times which depends on the number of nodes in their sub-trees and summing up all these number of visits wouldn't result time complexity of `Theta(n)`

Any idea or intuition on how to prove it ?

Comment: What I can think of as intuition , is that when we want to find the successor we either move to the right child and find the minimum in the sub-tree rooted by that node or we move up to an ancestors ! if we move to an ancestor we won't get back down again (?) , and if we go to the right child , it's like recursively doing the same actions , so by induction it's possible to prove that it's of O(n) !

Comment: One observation is that Min-Tree never visits a node more than once.

Comment: That's right , but it's done only once in the whole algorithm , the important thing is to prove how iterative findings of successor sum up to `Theta(n)`

Comment: Each edge will get traversed exactly twice: [http://i.stack.imgur.com/WlK5O.png](http://i.stack.imgur.com/WlK5O.png). Red arrow = call to `Min-Tree()`, blue arrow = `else` clause of `Successor()`. I tried writing a full answer but it got too long for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is easier to reason with edges rather than nodes. Let us reason based on the code of `Successor` function.

**Case 1 (`then` branch)**

For all nodes with a right child, we will visit the right subtree once ("right-turn" edge), then always visit the left subtree ("left-turn" edges) with `Min-Tree` function. We can prove that such traversal will create a path whose edges are unique - the edges will not be repeated in any traversal made from any other node with a right child, since the traversal ensures that you never visit any "right-turn" edge of other nodes on the tree. (Proof by construction).

**Case 2 (`else` branch)**

For all nodes without a right child (`else` branch), we will visit the ancestors by following "right-turn" edges until you have to make a "left-turn" edge or encounter the root of the binary tree. Again, the edges in the path generated are unique - will never be repeated in any other traversal made from any other node without a right child. This is because:

- Except for the starting node and the node reached by following "left-turn" edge, all other nodes in between has a right child (which means those are excluded from `else` branch). The starting node of course does not have a right child.
- Each node has a unique parent (only the root node does not have parent), and the path to parent is either "left-turn" or "right-turn" (the node is a left child or a right child). Given any node (ignoring the right child condition), there is only one path that creates the pattern: many "right-turn" then a "left-turn".
- Since the nodes in between have a right child, there is no way for an edge to appear in 2 traversal starting at different nodes. (Since we are currently considering nodes without a right child).

(The proof here is quite hand-waving, but I think it can be formally proven by contradiction).

Since the edges are unique, the total number of edges traversed in case 1 only (or case 2 only) will be O(n) (since the number of edges in a tree is equal to the number of vertices - 1). Therefore, after summing the 2 cases up, In-Order Traversal will be O(n).

Note that I only know each edge is visited at most once - I don't know whether all edges are visited or not from the proof, but the number of edges is bounded by the number of vertices, which is just right.

We can easily see that it is also Omega(n) (each node is visited once), so we can conclude that it is Theta(n).

Comment: I guess that each edge is visited exactly twice as it is depicted here : http://i.stack.imgur.com/WlK5O.png 
Is your proof still valid regarding this graph ?

Comment: @ArianHosseinzadeh: I proved that for the case where there is right child, the total number of edges visited is O(n), and for the case where there is no right child, the total number of edges visited is also O(n). Combined together, it is O(n).

Comment: @ArianHosseinzadeh: Actually, your picture is showing what my proof is trying to show: there are no 2 blue lines going over 1 edge, and there are also no 2 red lines going over 1 edge.

Answer (score 3):

The given program runs in Θ(N) time. Θ(N) doesn't mean that each node is visited exactly once. Remember there is a constant factor. So Θ(N) could actually be limited by **5 N** or **10 N** or even a **1000 N**. So as such it doesn't give you an exact count on the number of times a node is visited.

The Time complexity of in-order iterative traversal of Binary Search Tree can be analyzed as follows,

Consider a Tree with N nodes,

Let the execution time be denoted by the complexity function `T(N)`.

Let the left sub tree and right sub tree contain X and N-X-1 nodes respectively,

Then the time complexity `T(N) = T(X) + T(N-X-1) + c`,

Now consider the two extreme cases of a `BST`,

**CASE 1:** A `BST` which is perfectly balanced, i.e. both the sub trees have equal number of nodes. For example consider the BST shown below,

```
                        10
                       /  \
                      5   14
                     / \  / \
                    1  6 11 16
```

For such a Tree the complexity function is,

```
T(N) = 2 T(⌊N/2⌋) + c
```

Master Theorem gives us a complexity of Θ(N) in this case.

**CASE 2:** A fully unbalanced BST, i.e. either the left sub tree or right sub tree is empty. There for X = 0. For example consider the `BST` shown below,

```
               10
              /
             9
            /
           8
          /
         7
```

Now `T(N) = T(0) + T(N-1) + c`,

```
T(N) = T(N-1) + c
T(N) = T(N-2) + c + c
T(N) = T(N-3) + c + c + c
 .
 .
 .
T(N) = T(0) + N c
```

Since T(N) = K, where K is a constant,

T(N) = K + N c

There for T(N) = Θ(N).

Thus the complexity is `Θ(N)` for all the cases.

Comment: You don't relate your answer to any part of the algorithm and that makes me confused , can you please explain how it is related to iterative findings of successors ?

Answer (score 0):

We focus on edges instead of nodes. 
( to have a better intuition look at this picture : https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlK5O.png)

We claim that in this algorithm every edge is visited at most twice, (actually it's visited exactly twice);

First time when it's traversed downward and and the second time when it's traversed upward.
To visit an edge more than twice , we have to traverse that edge it downward again : down , up , ***down*** , ....

We prove that it's not possible to have a second downward visit of an edge.

Let's assume that we traverse an `edge (u , v)` downward for the second time , this means that one of the ancestors of `u` has a successor which is a decedent of `u`.

This is not possible :

We know that when we are traversing an edge upward , we are looking for a left-turn edge to find a successor , so while `u` is on the left side of the the successor, successor of this successor is on the right side of it , by moving to the right side of a successor (to find its successor) reaching `u` again and therefore `edge (u,v)` again is impossible. (to find a successor we either move to the right or to the up but not to the left)